# Проблемы с кириллицей в MySQL в команде INSERT

Tags: mysql

Запуская следующий код SQL(под windows10):

```
USE books;

INSERT INTO Customers VALUES
(1, 'Иван Петров', 'бул. Гудвина, 12', 'г. Изумрудный'),
(2, 'Петр Сидоров', 'ул. Незнайки, 34', 'г. Солнечный'),
(3, 'Сидор Иванов', 'пер. Поттера, 56', 'п.г.т. Хогвартс');
```

В таблицу попадают вместо символов кириллицы вопросительные знаки вида ?????????(не та кодировка).
Какую кодировку задать ? cp1251 не работает.

Comment: Скорее всего, у Вас не правильная кодировка БД, или, при соединении с БД вы не указываете кодировку, которую собираетесь использывать для данных. Тоесть, если по умолчанию у Вас например кодировка БД UTF-8, при соединении не указываете кодировку с того же терминала или кода, а она в windows-1251, то символы кирилицы от вас скорее евсего не поймет, но латинице понимает, потому и ??????.

Comment: @NikPashchuk Как поменять кодировку MySQL ?